# Finding the max and min in dictionary as tuples python

Tags: python, python-3.x

so given this dictionary i'm trying to find the max value and min value

```
{'Female' :[18,36,35,49,19],'Male' :[23,22,6,36,46]}
```

the output should be in tuples for example
key: (min,max)

```
Female: (18,49)
Male: (6,46)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{key:(max(d[key]),min(d[key])) for key in d}
```

This will return

```
{'Female': (49, 18), 'Male': (46, 6)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = {'Female' :[18,36,35,49,19],'Male' :[23,22,6,36,46]}
>>> dd = {k:(min(d[k]), max(d[k])) for k in d}
>>> print(dd)
{'Male': (6, 46), 'Female': (18, 49)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an example:

```
dct = {'Female' :[18,36,35,49,19],'Male' :[23,22,6,36,46]}
for key in dct:
    print(key, (min(dct[key]), max(dct[key])))
```

will print:

```
# Female (18, 49)
# Male (6, 46)
```

I'll leave you the task of finding out how the `:` is going to be inserted.

The [Python documentation on built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) is very helpful on how `min`, `max` and `print` can be used.

---

An alternative would be to simply create a `minmax` function:

```
>>> def minmax(some_list):
...     return min(some_list), max(some_list)

>>> {key: minmax(values) for key, values in dct.items()}
{'Female': (18, 49), 'Male': (6, 46)}
```

Or if you want it faster I recently created a package containing such a function ([`iteration_utilities.minmax`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/minmax.html)) that requires only one-pass (and thus less comparisons):

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import minmax
>>> {key: minmax(values) for key, values in dct.items()}
{'Female': (18, 49), 'Male': (6, 46)}
```